# How Check internet connection in android?

Tags: android

I have this code and working but i can not put code to check internet 
I wont check internet if available the app go to my URL if not show me message
"notinternet available" .the code working vey good but i can not forwod aftr connction to go for me URL

```
code1
   HelooWebViewActivity.java

   package xonmp.hellowebview;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.KeyEvent;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

   @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class HelloWebViewActivity 
    extends Activity {


    private WebView mWebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_web_view);



    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

   }

   private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

   // @Override
    public boolean shoudOverridUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

  }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
   {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
    mWebView.goBack();
    return true;
        }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

   }
   }



  code 2
  AndroidManifest.xml

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xonmp.hellowebview"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="xonmp.hellowebview.HelloWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

  </manifest>


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xonmp.hellowebview"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="xonmp.hellowebview.HelloWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

   </manifest>




  code 3

  Activity_heloo_web_view.xml

  <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".HelloWebViewActivity" 
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you :

```
public boolean isConnectionAvailable(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobileNetWork = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    return wifi.isConnected() || mobileNetWork.isConnected();
  }
```

use something like this :

```
if(isConnectionAvailable(getApplicationContext()) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
} else {
//Toast message 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No internet avalaible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And inside menifest put the following permission outside the application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: if i wont add Button(Retry) when No internet available to Refresh page ??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should sort it

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

You will also need this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare in manifest that you'll need access to network state, you can do it in this way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then you'll need an instance of ConnectivityManager to get the state of the network. In the developer docs says that it is used to get the network status (wifi , mobile).

Get an instance of it in this way:

```
ConnectivityManager manager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

And then to get the wifi status you can use this:

```
NetworkInfo wifiStatus = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

And for mobile network

```
NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

And to get the status of the network you can use the method

```
isConnected();
```

And using them all together in a method: let's say **CheckConnectionAvailable**

```
public boolean CheckConnectionAvailable(){

  ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
NetworkInfo mobile = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
return wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected();
}
```

**Edited**

If you want to use a button to refresh the page you have 2 ways of doing it.

But ill show you how to do it in xml because so you keep your code more cleaner and separate code from layout. Let's say as example you have this button declared in xml.

```
<Button id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Refresh Page" android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

And in your code you'll need the method you passed in the `android:onClick`.

```
public void onClick(View view){
   switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.button:
     boolean isAvailable = CheckConnectionAvailable();
     if(isAvailable){
        Toast.makeText(this,"message you wanna show if theres a connection available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
      }else {
  Toast.makeText(this,"message you wanna show if theres not a connection available",
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: if i wont add Button(Retry) when No internet available to Refresh page ??